# r filter dataframe group_by, and find cumusm

Tags: r, filter, group-by, cumsum

I have a df in the following manner

```
id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4)
val = c("AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "CCC")
df = data.frame(id= id, val=val)
```

I want to remove any group that does not contain the given string at least once (here "AAA" ),
and then to find cumsum of occurrence of "AAA" by group.
In the example the first element "BBB"  in group id=4 is removed as it appears before "AAA".

the output will look like

```
id =  c(  1,    1,    3,    4,    4)
val = c("AAA","BBB","AAA","AAA","CCC")
cs =  c(  1,     1,    2,    3,    3)
df = data.frame(id= id, val=val, cs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following with `dplyr` library :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(if(any(val == 'AAA')) row_number() >= match('AAA', val) else FALSE) %>%
  mutate(cs = cur_group_id())
  #For dplyr < 1.0.0
  #ungroup %>% mutate(cs = match(id, unique(id)))

#     id val      cs
#  <dbl> <chr> <int>
#1     1 AAA       1
#2     1 BBB       1
#3     3 AAA       2
#4     4 AAA       3
#5     4 CCC       3
```

We select all the rows after `"AAA"` value for each `id`.